# Selecting values greater than x in 2d array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have np 2d array (called old_array) which looks like this:

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
4 3 5 1 6 7 3 2 8
8 3 4 1 8 3 2 9 3
7 3 5 8 2 5 9 2 6

Trying to select only values greater than 4 and would like to have output like this:

5 6 7 8 9
5 6 7 8
8 8 9 
7 5 8 5 9 6

I was trying to use new_array = old_array[old_array>4] but not getting desired solution.
Any explanation what I am doing wrong, or how this should be done. Also trying to avoid loops if possible.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, your desired output isn't exactly a 2D array, right? How would you like to store it? Are you looking for [masked arrays](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/maskedarray.generic.html), e.g., `np.ma.masked_array(a, a < 5)`?

Comment: I think not, not sure .... but in the next step from new_array I would like to evaluate mean, median, standard deviation for each row. This is final goal. Not sure if I am clear enough.

Comment: What's the `out.shape` of your array `out` of output? Is it one-dimensional? `numpy` is not designed to work with arrays that contains other arrays of different length.

Comment: I am getting no results since I do not have idea how to deal with this.

Comment: It looks like you need `np.array([5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 7, 5, 8, 5, 9, 6])` or `np.array([array([5, 6, 7, 8, 9]), array([5, 6, 7, 8]), array([8, 8, 9]), array([7, 5, 8, 5, 9, 6])])`. A second one could be derived from the first one.

Answer (score 1):

If these arrays are NumPy arrays and you'd like to get the indexing of the elements rather than 4, you can use
`np.argwhere(array > 4)`
This function returns you another array with the indexes of the original array where the condition is True.

```py
np.argwhere(array>4)
array([[0, 4],
       [0, 5],
       [0, 6],
       [0, 7],
       [0, 8],
       [1, 2],
       [1, 4],
       [1, 5],
       [1, 8],
       [2, 0],
       [2, 4],
       [2, 7],
       [3, 0],
       [3, 2],
       [3, 3],
       [3, 5],
       [3, 6],
       [3, 8]])
```

Otherwise

```py
array>4
array([[False, False, False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [False, False,  True, False,  True,  True, False, False,  True],
       [ True, False, False, False,  True, False, False,  True, False],
       [ True, False,  True,  True, False,  True,  True, False,  True]])
```

In this case, you obtain a mask on which you can loop through.

Hope it works

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to force `numpy` to work in a way it is not designed for. It is **not** designed to work with arrays that contain rows of **not** equal length.

Now, as you are informed about that, you can still do it using [`np.split`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.split.html) but this is slow in general.

Here is a way to go along with:

```
x = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [4, 3, 5, 1, 6, 7, 3, 2, 8], [8, 3, 4, 1, 8, 3, 2, 9, 3], [7, 3, 5, 8, 2, 5, 9, 2, 6]])
trues = x > 4
row_lengths = np.sum(trues, axis=1)
split_idx = np.cumsum(row_lengths[:-1])
>>> np.split(x[trues], split_idx)
[array([5, 6, 7, 8, 9]),
 array([5, 6, 7, 8]),
 array([8, 8, 9]),
 array([7, 5, 8, 5, 9, 6])]
```

And some tests explaining how it works:

```
>>> trues
array([[False, False, False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [False, False,  True, False,  True,  True, False, False,  True],
       [ True, False, False, False,  True, False, False,  True, False],
       [ True, False,  True,  True, False,  True,  True, False,  True]])
>>> x[trues]
array([5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 7, 5, 8, 5, 9, 6])
>>> row_lengths
array([5, 4, 3, 6])
>>> split_idx
array([ 5,  9, 12], dtype=int32)
```